# Manipulação de data frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Olá,

Estou tentando manipular uma base de dados com 300+ observações, mas cada observação tem um número diferente de colunas. O problema é que a partir de determinado ponto, as colunas passam a se repetir, mas possuem diferentes valores e eu queria de alguma forma junta-las.

O que eu quero essencialmente é, dentro de um objeto, salvar as informações de cada observação de uma forma que ajude na visualização.

Por exemplo:

```
            a   b   c   d    e  c   d   e   c     d    e
    Obs_1   AA  BB  CC  8.3  A  SSD 2.3 RN  S76   5    A
    Obs_2   SS  DA  LL  5    A  SDD         AD23  8.2  A
```

E eu gostaria de transformar em algo assim:

```
         a   b    c      d   e
Obs_1   AA  BB  CC76    8.3  A
                SSD89   2.3  RN
                S76      5   A
Obs_2   SS  DA  LL       5   A
                SDD     
                AD23    8.2  A
```

É possível fazer isso de uma maneira não braçal no R? Note ainda que existem valores no banco de dados que não possuem valor, alguns valores o R completa com NA, outros ele simplesmente deixa em branco.

Comment: Por favor, se a data.frame se chamar `dados`, edite a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(dados, 20))`, para termos uma cópia exata da estrutura dos dados.

Comment: Do jeito que foi feita a pergunta, sem um conjunto de dados de exemplo, e difícil entender exatamente a natureza do problema.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se esse código ajuda. Estou testando com o `mtcars`. Você precisa instalar os pacotes `dplyr`, `tidyr` e `janitor`

```
mtcars
# renomeia as colunas para ficar parecido com seu exemplo
names(mtcars) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d")

mtcars %>% 
  slice(c(1, 2))

# A tibble: 2 x 11
      a     b     c     d     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   21.    6.  160.  110.    6.  160.  110.   21.    6.  160.  110.
2   21.    6.  160.  110.    6.  160.  110.   21.    6.  160.  110.


res <- mtcars %>% 
  # pega as primeiras linhas para ficar parecido com seu exemplo
  head(2) %>% 
  # transforma os nomes em unicos
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  # empilha todos os dados
  gather() %>% 
  # separa as colunas respectivas e os respectivos índices
  separate(key, c("letra", "numero"), sep = "_", fill = "right") %>% 
  # substitui NA por 1 no caso da primeira separação
  replace_na(list(numero = "1")) %>% 
  # completa as combinacoes de indices e letras que nao apareceram
  complete(letra, numero) %>% 
  # essa parte nao sei se precisa 
  group_by(letra, numero) %>% 
  summarise(res = first(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # espalha as letras nas colunas
  spread(letra, res)


res

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  numero     a     b      c      d
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1        21.  6.00 160.   110.  
2 2         0.  3.90   2.62  16.5 
3 3        NA   1.00   4.00   4.00
```